# How to pass querystring value into iframe src

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have a normal link button where I am getting data through like this

```
<a href="ViewRemarks.aspx?jobid=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"jobid") 
%>" id="btn_remarks" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter3" 
class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-outline-info " ><i class="fa fa-comments" ></i>
</a>
```

Note: in this button, I am getting data called job id

Then I took one bootstrap modal inside that modal I kept one child page like this

```
<iframe style="width: 470px; height: 195px;" id="Iframe1" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" src="ViewRemarks.aspx?jobid=null"></iframe>
```

Note: iframe is not showing in stackoverflow don't know why but yes that is an iframe so i kept one a before iframe.

But here I want to pass that particular jobid from that button inside the data table how can I solve this in asp.net or javascript anything is accepted please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So use the link target which will load the link in the iframe.

```
<iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe1" />
```

and the link

```
<a href="//example.com?foo=bar" target="iframe1">My LInk</a>
```

```html
<iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe1"></iframe>

<a href="//example.com?foo=bar" target="iframe1">My LInk</a>
```

Comment: i can't use directly link because i want that particular jobid, if I will click on that button it will take the jobid to the next page , but here I am showing that page into iframe so I have to pass that  particular jobid then my data table will fetch the data according to that job id

Comment: And when you click on the link the link opens in the iframe.... it will not open in a new page. Try it

Comment: no not working bcs it is just redirecting to the child page which i don't want I want to popup the modal and fetch data inside there if u have any other suggestions also no proble.

Comment: It is unclear how a link that targets the iframe redirects to the child page in the main window. The link targets the iframe so clicking on it will load the link in the iframe. Did you actually try what I suggested?

Comment: I edited the code to include an example that runs. You can see clicking on the link opens up the example domain in the iframe.

Comment: if u want to give some dynamic value like it will take the data directly from querystring how it will work ? it is working only in static link only.

Comment: Well you have a static link that PHP spits out. You can write a method that grabs the querystring value if you need to transform it. But why even set it as a querysting in the first place if you are seting it with php? a simple data attribute would be 100% better.

Comment: no i am working in asp.net, can u explain any method to get querystring value in asp.net?

Comment: Does not make a difference. So you are telling me that the URL in the link is not the url you want to show up in the iframe?

Comment: yaah i whant query  like this ViewRemarks.aspx?jobid=JCOM00165

Comment: JCOM00165 THE only thing i want dynamic rest all static or all should be dynamic anything.